# Codeigniter 3 Remove index.php Problems

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have a little project that i developed for a client in codeigniter 2.1.4 and now, he insists to migrate to codeigniter 3 DEV version. I know that's not a good ideea but...
My problem is that i can't remove the index.php from the url.

This is my .htaccess file :

```
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine on

  # Send request via index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I have removed the index.php from the config.php file

No luck

I reinstalled the LAMP server (i'm on Ubuntu 12.04'), reconfigured 
I have other projects on my local server developed on Codeigniter 2.1.4 and Laravel 4 and they work just fine but this one it's killing me.

Thank you!

Comment: Just out of curiosity: How is it that your client can differentiate between version 2 and 3 but cannot convert themselves?

Comment: @php_nub_qq ya, anyways i am reading what CI3 is all about :@

Comment: He can not but someone shoved this thing in his head.

Comment: Here are a couple of resources that actually show the code without a question mark. See if any of these help https://madhukaranand.wordpress.com/2013/09/08/codeigniter-urls/ http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Comment: I've already tried this option...

Answer (score 11):

I made this way:

Created the .htaccess in the root folder of the project with the content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|js|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

Then, in the config.php i modified this line.

From:

```
$config['url_suffix'] = 'index.php';
```

To:

```
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
```

Answer (score 6):

Kindly add the below codes to *.htaccess* file and include it directly to your */codeigniter_project_folder/.htacess*

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

If your Apache server has mod_rewrite enabled, you can easily remove this file by using a .htaccess file with some simple rules.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Remove the `?` after index.php

Answer (score 2):

Add following lines in .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

And also Edit **application/config/config.php** file. with

```
$config[‘index_page’] = “”;
$config[‘uri_protocol’] = “AUTO“;
```

It will Work.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a `.htacess` file in your project root folder `/Your_codeigniter_project_folder/.htacess` and paste this code

   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
2. set a base URL in config.php file `$config['base_url'] = 'http://yourhost/CI_project_folder/';`
3. set URL suffix `$config['url_suffix'] = '.php';`

*** If not work please check this ***

4. Make sure in your root folder where `.htacess` stay there have not any file which name is same like your controller name.
   Example: you have a `users.php` controller also you have a file in `/Your_codeigniter_project_folder/users.php`
   If have please remove it `/Your_codeigniter_project_folder/users.php`
5. Make sure your server is rewrite mode on( remove # from start of this line)

   LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Answer (score 0):

create new .htaccess file on root of your CI project and add your code there. Do not change .htaccess file on application folder. That's work for me

Answer (score 0):

Just Download CI version `2.2.0`

Copy `.htaccess` and `htaccess.txt` from root and paste it in your Codeigniter 3 project.

Don't forget to change project name from `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an a new htaccess file in your www/project_folder or your htdocs/project_folder
2. Make sure mod_rewrite is working my using `echo phpinfo()`
3. Simply paste the following code and it should work:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project_folder/index.php/$1 [L]  
   </IfModule>

   <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
       ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
   </IfModule>
   ```
4. Change the project folder to that of your own

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about the project path uppercase.
i.e. if the base_url is `http://localhost/ci/` and the directory name is `CI`, it may not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .htaccess file on your project ex: "your_project/[put .htaccess here].
Remember to name the file .htaccess with dot first

then you can add code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

this code worked fine on my project

Answer (score -1):

I have clone the git repository again and made a clean install of the lamp and now it works.