# Issues in removing index.php in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to access my URL's without `index.php` in CodeIgniter. Here is my `Blog` controller

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        echo 'hello world';
    }

    public function about() {
        echo 'about page';
    }
}
```

Now I can access `index`  via `http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/Blog`, but I need to access it with this URL `http://localhost/codeigniter/Blog`.

**NOTE**

I removed index.php from config file
`.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]

Environment
```

Windows, XAMPP, PHP Version 5.6.3

Comment: google it, "codeginiter removing the index.php file".

Comment: Edit your `.htaccess` file, click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169545/codeigniter-3-remove-index-php-problems) to see how.

Comment: I tried but didnt work for me

Comment: Do 2 things, make sure you have apache configured to use `.htaccess`  and you have `mod_rewrite.c` module enabled.

Comment: Click on green apache icon in tray, Apache > Apache modules > rewrite_module is checked ?

Comment: I cant find that in my settings:)

Comment: enabled the rewrite_module in apache

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove "index.php" in codeigniter's path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-path)

Answer (score 3):

How to removed index.php from url has been asked so many times, It is the same as what is for **codeigniter 2 and 3**.

For Xampp With Codeigniter Windows

Find application/config/config.php

**Replace This**

`$config['base_url'] = "";`

**With This**

`$config['base_url'] = "your-project-url";`

**Replace This**

`$config['index_page'] = "index.php"`

**With This**

`$config['index_page'] = ""`

In main directory create file called .htaccess

I use code below works fine for me in xampp in windows. More htacces [here](https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

**Note:** make sure your controllers are like example Welcome.php instead of welcome.php also you might need to create new routes in your route.php if remove index.php

Answer (score 2):

I just now struggled with this part again, even after being used to Codeigniter for 2+ years.

None of the answers helped me exactly, including the [official Codeigniter's page](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file) about this, so I'm posting the solution that worked for me.

1. Enable Rewrite engine

   ```
   sudo a2enmod rewrite
   ```
2. Change Apache's config file to allow folders to allow overriding of default security setting

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
   ```

Under the "Directory" options depending on the location of your files, edit

```
    AllowOverride None
```

to

```
    AllowOverride All
```

e.g.: My server files are in "/var/www", so my final result for corresponding Directory options is:

```
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

3. Create a ".htaccess" file in the root of your Codeigniter project, i.e.: along with where applications, system folders exist.

In the file, put the following:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

4. In config/config.php file, change:

   ```
   $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
   ```

to

```
    $config['index_page'] = '';
```

5. Restart apache2:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

To remove `index.php` create a `.htaccess` file in the same folder as your site’s main index.php file.
Then add the following code to this newly created .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

this code have two parts 
1 - remove index.php 
2 - redirect all site requests to the index file.

Comment: Can you check if  `mod_rewrite` is enabled in your apache or not ?

Comment: ii have checked it ts enabled

Answer (score 1):

Please change your base_url path which exist in application/config

```
$config['base_url'] ='localhost/projectname/index.php'
```

to

```
$config['base_url'] ='localhost/projectname/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_rewrite
restart your apache server
and in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step:-1** Open the folder `“application/config”` and open the file `“config.php“`. find and replace the below code in `config.php` file.

```
 //find the below code   
    $config['index_page'] = "index.php" 
    //replace with the below code
    $config['index_page'] = ""
```

**Step:-2** Write below code in .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

**Step:-3** In some case the default setting for uri_protocol does not work properly. To solve this problem just open the file `“application/config/config.php“`, then find and replace the below code

```
//find the below code
$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO"
//replace with the below code
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

Answer (score 0):

in config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

in `.htacess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

finally this is worked fine for me. i have changed `.htaccess`  file with this content

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /codeigniter

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]


    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
        # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
        # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
        # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

And these changes made

```
    $config['index_page'] = "index.php" 
        //replace with the below code
        $config['index_page'] = ""
$config['base_url'] = "your-project-url";
```

Answer (score 0):

### Alright, i've been strugling with this for two days, and here is my solution for XAMPP and CodeIgniter 3

Create new ".htaccess" file in root directory (not in CodeIgniter's application folder, where there's another htacces file, don't touch that one), with this inside:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Then, find and change this values on **config.php** (CodeIgniter file, on config folder):

```
$config['base_url']     = 'localhost/YourProject';
$config['index_page']   = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Finally, on **httpd.conf** (Apache config file), find:

`#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

and uncomment the line (remove #).

---

That's it! Now

`localhost/myProject/news`

works as if I write

```
localhost/myProject/index.php/news
```

Answer (score 0):

My Codeigniter version is 3.1.11
I'm trying all types of code in htaccess but that does not work then I was found this code.

Place the .htaccess file in the project folder like this:
htdocs/your_project/.htaccess
Try this new code for .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /your-project-directory-name/ 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```