# Codeigniter 404 page not found with form

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I just started to use Codeigniter, and can't understand why what I'm doing isn't working.

My controller is like that:

```
class Tienda extends CI_Controller {

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('inicio_view');
    }
    public function entrar(){
        $nom= $this->input->post('nom');
        $pass= $this->input->post('pass');

        if($nom && $pass){
            $data['nom']=$nom;
            $data['pass']=$pass;
            $this->load->model('Login_model');
            $user=$this->Login_model->get_usuario($nom, $pass);

            var_dump($user);

            if ($user[0]['id']=='1'){
                $this->load->view('Catalogo_view');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My initial view

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>TIENDA</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>TIENDA</h1>
        <div class="form">
            <form action="<?php echo base_url('Tienda/entrar');?>" method="post">
              Usuario: <input type="text" name="nom"/>
              <br/>
              Contraseña: <input type="text" name="pass"/>
              <br/>
             <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
            </form>
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

And in the login_model I'm just calling to get the user and the pass

```
class Login_model extends CI_Model {

        public function get_usuario($nom,$pass){
            //$query = $this->db->get_where('usuarios',array('nom'=>$nom,'pass'=>$pass));
            $query = $this->db-> query('SELECT id FROM usuarios where nom = "'.$nom.'" and pass = "'.$pass.'";');
            return $query->result_array();
        }
}
```

I don't know how many hours I've been searching and changing things, but it still doesn't work. Also, I checked almost every post of people who had that problem, but still can't make it work.

My catalog_view is just a h1 that says it works, because I just wanted to see if I can make it work but... I just don't know what it's happening.
If there's any help here, it would be appreciated!

Comment: sure the file name of controller Tienda start with 'T' not 't'

Comment: and try action="<?php echo base_url();?>Tienda/entrar"

Comment: @AbanoubMakram Yes, the controller starts with T. Also just checked to change the action to the one you posted and still doesn't works. I really don't know where's the error...

Comment: the controller file ?

Comment: @AbanoubMakram Yes, the file starts with T too!

Comment: are set the base_url() in config ?

Comment: what about .htaccess file ? try to do like this https://gist.github.com/philipptempel/4226750

Comment: In the base_rul() I have nothing, but since it's localhost... do I have to put it? In other simple exercises in class we didn't put anything and it worked. Also, the htacess, don't really understand what I have to put on "RewriteBase". Checked htaccess, tried many things and still doesn't work, now it goes to xampp's dashboard

Comment: project folder name in RewriteBase

Comment: The project folder name is Tienda too and nothing...

Comment: see this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30501756/issues-in-removing-index-php-in-codeigniter-3

Comment: can you print base_url() ?

Comment: How do I print the base_url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the answer in case anyone needs it.
In config, I had to put "localhost/index.php/Tienda" so it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks okay to me. I can suggest you few checklists.

1. Make sure Controller and model file names must match with the class name. `Tienda.php` and `Login_model.php`.
2. View file name in lower case and while loading it also follow the same case `catalogo_view.php` and the file must be present inside the `/application/view/` directory. If you are using any sub-directory the `$this->load->view('mydir/catalogo_view')`.
3. While accessing URL: please make sure you have given the right URL and in lower case. `http://your-url/tienda/entrar`, if it doesn't work then try `http://your-url/index.php/tienda/entrar`.
4. Please make sure you have configured `base_url` and `.htaccess` properly. Here I am giving you link to access few resources for more information. 
   https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html
   https://gist.github.com/philipptempel/4226750

Comment: Nothing works... Could it be a problem with my xampp? Ok, I have other projects from my class and all of them work, but mine isn't, and everything is the same.