# Remove index.php from url in codeigniter-3 in ubantu14.04

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I  have Ubantu 14.04 machine also I checked [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

My phpinfo() says rewrite_module is Enable also I have done changes into config.php

> $config['index_page'] = '';

and below is my .htaccess file on root

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: may duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169545/codeigniter-3-remove-index-php-problems

Comment: yes I know but i did't get any solution from above link

Comment: `base_url()` is set [correct](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php#L14)? Also try with `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]`.

Comment: yes @Tpojka, thanks for reply me , I got solution just added <Directory /var/www/html >
  Order allow,deny
  AllowOverride All
  Allow from all
  Require all granted
</Directory> into file /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf and it's woking fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution just added

```
<Directory /var/www/html >
   Order allow,deny
   AllowOverride All
   Allow from all
   Require all granted 
 </Directory>
```

into file /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf and it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
# Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On
#  Rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```