# .htaccess not working and confusion

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've looked at numerous questions regarding .htaccess not working.
Tried them all but it still won't work for mine.

It was still working for me before, the problem started when i deleted the .htaccess file inside the application folder.

The tutorial i was following didn't specifically mention to delete that htaccess but just to copy it to the root. So basically, when it was still working i had 2 htaccess files, with the application folder and inside the application folder.

Right now, even if i deleted the .htaccess file inside the application leaving only 1 .htaccess in my project root, it still won't work.

I still have to include 'index.php' for the url to work.

It won't necessarily show me 404 when i don't include the index.php.

It just shows me this page,

[image]

This is the content of my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

My config file.

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Apart from that, i already tried, refreshing my wamp connection, shutting down my pc then turning it on again.

I don't know whats wrong since it worked for me the first time around even if i have 2 htaccess it still won't. Something happened when i accidentally deleted that 1 file.

My system is windows 7 32-bit, and i'm using WAMP. I already turned on rewrite module for apache on my wamp. I'm using the latest codeigniter, 3.1.2

This may also give a hint,

When i load my view, the css url won't work.

The css url shouldv been `localhost/project/css/bootstrap.min.css`

however, same result, same page it shows above.

I also have this on my httpd.conf on my apache.

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Comment: Look into `RewriteBase`, as this is a relative path/directory. Unless it's directly on `localhost` as the root.

Comment: I just installed my wamp yesterday with the new codeigniter version so i don't know what rewritebase, that's the first time i've seen it.

this is the directory of my project.

C:\wamp\www\project\

Comment: Try putting the following under your `RewriteEngine` definition: `RewriteBase /project/`.

Comment: The rule you posted works fine andtrewrites everything to index.php eg : **/foobar** to **/index.php/foobar** I think the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I'm not experienced in the technical stuff, would you recommend if i just uninstalled wamp then reinstalled it again?

Comment: I uninstalled and installed it again, yet the problem still persist.

Comment: To check if your htaccess file is working or not , read this article https://helponnet.com/2021/05/14/know-wether-htaccess-is-working-on-apache/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this works but i've found an htaccess that was specifically mentioned for a ci3 htaccess problem.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

not much difference, just that it removed the '/' before the index.php and replaced the '/' to '?' after the index.php

Is this because i am using CI 3?

[Codeigniter 3 remove index.php problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169545/codeigniter-3-remove-index-php-problems)